# RTSP DESCRIBE on Axis Camera with libcurl v7.43.0 returns RTSP errorcode 400

Tags: c++, libcurl, rtsp

I am obtaining a HTTP error 400 in response to the folowing RTSP URL being processed by the function shown below.

DESCRIBE rtsp://root:pass@192.168.1.47/axis-media/media.amp ?videocodec=h264/

The IP camera I am using is a recent AXIS H264 camera.

The libcurl version I am using is v7.43.0

bool CHttpClientCurl::Get()
{
    // initialize curl
    CURLcode res = CURLE_OK;
    if (m_curl == NULL)
    {
        m_sError = L"CURL handle is NULL.";
        return false;
    }

```
m_sBuffer.clear();
// initialize this curl session
curl_easy_reset(m_curl);
char sUrl[8192];
wcstombs(sUrl, m_sUrl.c_str(), m_sUrl.length());
sUrl[m_sUrl.length()] = '\0';

curl_version_info_data *data = curl_version_info(CURLVERSION_NOW);
printf("    cURL V%s loaded\n", data->version);
if (m_curl != NULL) {
    curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_RTSP);
    res = curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_URL, sUrl); 


    // request server options
    printf("\nRTSP: OPTIONS %s\n", sUrl);
    curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_RTSP);
    res = curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_RTSP_STREAM_URI, sUrl); 
    curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_RTSP_REQUEST, CURL_RTSPREQ_DESCRIBE); 
    curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_RTSP_TRANSPORT, "RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=64378-64379");
//  curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_RTSP_SESSION_ID, "56789");
    res = curl_easy_perform(m_curl);
    int64_t nHttpCode = 0;
    curl_easy_getinfo(m_curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &nHttpCode);
    m_nStatusCode = nHttpCode;
    if (res != CURLE_OK)
    {
        std::wstringstream ss;
        ss << curl_easy_strerror(res);
        m_sError = L"Error occurred - " + std::wstring(ss.str());
        return false;
    }
    else if (nHttpCode != 200)
    {
        SetErrorString(nHttpCode);
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

}

Could someone advise me if there is a mistake in the URL or in the C++ function?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What RTSP URL scheme to use for connection to Axis network cameras?This is described in the documentation of your Axis camera. You do need to look for it though. The examples below use vlc as application to remotely view your network camera.
Older Axis (eg: 207, 210) network cameras use the following scheme for an H264 stream (replace mpeg4 with mpeg2 to change the video format).
vlc rtsp://myaxiscamera/mpeg4/media.amp --rtsp-http
Newer Axis (eg: Q 1755/Q 1755-E) network cameras use this scheme:
vlc rtsp://myaxiscamera/axis-media/media.amp --rtsp-http

Comment: Please read the following URL: for a description of the RTSP syntax for each Axis Camera model: http://www.soleratec.com/support/rtsp/rtsp_listing?camera_company=AXIS

Comment: I have an answer which I will post in 4 hours.

Answer (score 1):

The way to solve this problem is to first provide user credentials in the rtsp string and second issue a RTSP DESCRIBE twice in a row consecutively. The first RTSP DESCRIBE request will result in a HTTP 401 error code if user credentials are incorrect or missing. The second DESCRIBE request will result in a HTTP 200 OK code. After the second RTSP DESCRIBE returns HTTP 200 OK, you may issue a RTSP SETUP request followed by a RTSP PLAY request which should return HTTP 200 and create the RTSP stream.

Comment: @Roman R. , May I ask how to use the RTSP  on an Axis 
camera with dual h264 and mpeg4 streaming hardware support to stream MPEG4? Thank you.

Comment: See [Page 17 here](http://www.axis.com/files/manuals/vapix_video_streaming_52937_en_1307.pdf): `DESCRIBE rtsp://myserver/.../media.amp?videocodec=h264&resolution=640x480`. I suppose this is what you are looking for.

Comment: @RomanR., Thank you for your reply to my question. May I ask what the full URL for "Page 17 here" is as well as the *full* rtsp DESCRIBE RTSP URL? Thank you,

Comment: @Roman R., Thank you for your reply to my question. May I ask what the full URL for "Page 17 here" is as well as the full rtsp DESCRIBE RTSP URL? Thank you,

Comment: @Roman R, I believe there is an typographical error in your comment 8 minutes ago. I wish to find out how to stream ** MPEG4 ** and not H264 over a Axis camera using the RTSP protocol. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Roman R., I believe there is an typographical error in your comment 16 minutes ago. I wish to find out how to stream ** MPEG4 ** and not H264 over a Axis camera using the RTSP protocol. Thank you very much.

Comment: H.264 is also MPEG-4 (MPEG-4 Part 10). If you want MPEG-4 Part 2 then keyword is `mpeg4`. See page 24 of the same document.

Comment: @Roman R., I just scanned the document you referenced earlier in this thread,http://www.axis.com/files/manuals/vapix_video_streaming_52937_en_1307.pdf and it appears to say rtsp://192.168.2.47/axis-media/media.amp for both h264 streams and mpeg streams. However, when I test the mpeg stream using C++ and libcurl  and the string ,rtsp://192.168.2.47/axis-media/media.amp, i get back a RTSP error code 404, not found. On the other hand, rtsp://192.168.2.47/axis-media/media.amp works okay for H264. Please tell me what I am doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Page 24 lists parameters you can place in the RTSP URI. You need a fragment with `media.amp?videocodec=mpeg4` and possibly other parameters of your interest.

Comment: @Roman R., I just tested a fragment with rtsp://.....media.amp?videocodec=mpeg4 and received a RTSP Error 400 Bad Request. When I tested a fragment with rtsp://.....media.amp?videocodec=h264 and received a RTSP OK. Why does the fragment with h264 work and not the fragment with rtsp://.....media.amp?videocodec=mpeg4? Thank you.